# Jquery change event to work with all fields with same class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run jquery on changing values in multiple input fields. For example: I have 6 input type `file` fields. I want to set upload limit on all file fields with single jquery function.

To achieve this, I used this jquery code

```
 $('.image_size_check').change(function(){
     $('.image_size_check').each(function(){
        var sizeInKB = this.files[0].size/1024; //converting bytes into kb
        var sizeLimit= 200;
    
        if (sizeInKB >= sizeLimit) {
            alert("Max file for image is 200KB");
            $(this).val('');
        }
    });
});
```

But issue with this code is that, this code runs only when I make change in first file field. When I select file on second field, third field and so on, then this code doesn't work.

How do I make this code run (without using `onchange` event at attribute of input field) on selecting file on every file field present on page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the console errors. It clearly tells you the issues. When you loop through the inputs, only the first input has value while others doesn't have any value due to which `this.files` is null and hence `this.files[0].size` causes error:

```js
$('.image_size_check').change(function() {
  $('.image_size_check').each(function() {
    if (this.files.length) {
      var sizeInKB = this.files[0].size / 1024; //converting bytes into kb
      var sizeLimit = 200;

      if (sizeInKB >= sizeLimit) {
        alert("Max file for image is 200KB");
        $(this).val('');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
Hello <input class="image_size_check" type="file" /><br />Hello <input class="image_size_check" type="file" /><br />Hello <input class="image_size_check" type="file" /><br />Hello <input class="image_size_check" type="file" /><br />Hello <input class="image_size_check"
  type="file" /><br />Hello <input class="image_size_check" type="file" /><br />Hello <input class="image_size_check" type="file" /><br />Hello <input class="image_size_check" type="file" /><br />Hello <input class="image_size_check" type="file" /><br />Hello
<input class="image_size_check" type="file" /><br />
```